# webdriver-manager update --ie throws error

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, protractor

When I try to download ie driver for protractor testing, I do

```
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

but I get the below error

```
(node:17636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid Version: .3.150.2
at new SemVer (C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\semver\semver.js:323:11)
at compare (C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\semver\semver.js:614:10)
at Function.gt (C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\semver\semver.js:643:10)
at C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\binaries\iedriver_xml.js:43:33
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[21:41:10] I/update - selenium standalone: file exists C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[21:41:10] I/update - selenium standalone: selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar up to date
[21:41:10] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_94.0.4606.61.zip
[21:41:10] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_94.0.4606.61.zip
[21:41:10] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_94.0.4606.61.exe up to date
[21:41:10] I/update - geckodriver: file exists C:\Users\francisp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.30.0.zip
[21:41:10] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.30.0.zip
[21:41:10] I/update - geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.30.0.exe up to date
```

Can somebody help please? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this below and it worked.

```
webdriver-manager update --ie --versions.ie=3.9.0
```

instead of

```
webdriver-manager update --ie
```

Also while starting the server, you have to use

```
webdriver-manager start --ie --versions.ie=3.9.0
```

instead of

```
webdriver-manager start
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.